# When using graphics mods such as OptiFine, do I need to patch server or only client?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods, minecraft-mods, minecraft-optifine

I found a mod for Minecraft that adds a lot of adjustments and optimizations to the graphics handling, [OptiFine](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/249637-173-optifine-hd-f-fps-boost/).

However, I'm a bit unclear whether I need to patch the server in addition to the client.

Is there a common "knowledge" to this I'm lacking? Such as "yes, you will always have to patch the server"?

If not, does anyone know specifically for this mod, OptiFine, if I need to patch the server as well?

And... if I need to patch the server, does it do anything permanent to my world, such that if I later on decide to remove it, I can still play on the same world without problems?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You only need to patch the client, as all this does is managing how things are load and displayed.

For communication it just requests more chunks if you want to display more, there is nothing that needs to be changed server side to accomplish that. So, there is no need to patch the server.

Answer (score 3):

No, as long it is not a mod that affects gameplay, only the graphics. It will not affect your world, nor does the server need to be patched.

I am not certain about OptiFine as I never tried it, but it should work fine when only modded client-side.

Answer (score 2):

Optifine is a client only mod. Actually adding in Optifine to a server (with Forge) will throw a ClassNotFound exception.

(I did this to my pack a few days ago, wondered why it wouldn't load!)

Answer (score 0):

No Optifine doesn't need to be patched server side -just on your client. All it does is handle your graphics for the game , shader packs etc and gives you more settings on your client.

Comment: This does not add anything relevant that any of the existing answers don't already state. Please keep in mind that duplicate answers are frowned upon here and may be subject to deletion.

Answer (score 0):

Even I had that question on my mind, but I got it figured out - turns out it's a client-side only modification. You don't need others on the server to install it, since it just changes how stuff *looks*, not how stuff *works*.
To use it with a Forge client or server though, only *some* versions of Forge work with some versions of Optifine, I guess.

> For the most part, OptiFine will work with almost any version of Forge on
> the same version of Minecraft, but some WILL be incompatible. For best
> results, you should use the recommended version of Forge that is listed in
> the OptiFine changelog.